# How can I make all my javascript libraries load?

Tags: javascript

I have couple .js files I'm importing into a larger project. I've found that the project can't actually access them, and, as a result, I tried boiling it down to its most basic code to test. Essentially, I have one HTML file that loads the .js files using

```
    <script src="Files/data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Files/tally.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

data.js looks like this:

```
var data= {};
data.values=[];
data.values["Philadelphia"]=10;
data.values["level"]=109;

    data.getValue=function(level){...}//returns 109

    data.checkValues=function(level){...}//returns true
```

Tally looks like this:

```
var enemyTally= {};
    enemyTally.cities=[];
    enemyTally.cities["Philadelphia"]=12;
    enemyTally.cities["Boston"]=0;
    enemyTally.cities["New York"]=0;

    enemyTally.getTally=new function(level){...}//should return 12

    enemyTally.add=new function(level){...}
```

When I attempt to run some of this using code like this:

```
    var level="Philadelphia";
    var val=data.getValue(level);
    //var val2=enemyTally.getTally(level);
    document.writeln(data.checkValues("level"));
    document.writeln(data.getValue("level"));
    document.writeln(enemyTally.getTally(level));
```

My page reads `true 109` instead of `true 109 12`. I don't know why it isn't loading the other file. I know it's not an error with `getTally()`, as it's identical to `data.getValue`. The only reason I have tally is because I copied it from my more complicated project to see if it would work here. I'm not terribly familiar with JavaScript at all - I'm coming from Java for a project with a friend - and this is stumping me. I noticed that if I reinstate the commented out var declaration, the whole thing doesn't work- nothing writes.

I've done some reading, and it's led me to think that it could be an issue with the whole asynchronous loading thing, but reloading the page or browser doesn't fix it. It does the same thing in both Firefox and Chrome. I can code my functions to do what I want, and the general structure of the files seems to be right for what I'm doing, but they won't load and it's driving me nuts. Any simple JS help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I edited the code to show my problem, and the solution (turns out in not copying my code into SO I actually fixed the problem, which made it tough for you guys to fix.) I had "new" before my functions in enemyTally. Whoops. Thanks to those who did help, though.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant `tally` instead of `Tally`

```
document.write(tally.getTally(level));
```

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds. +1

Comment: That was a typo in the question, not the code. When I copied code into the question, I changed a couple things to make it a bit clearer. The in-code pointers line up correctly. I just double checked to make sure.

Comment: The scripts are loaded one after the other, it's not asynchronous. Your best bet is to post the code in the getTally function, even if you THINK it's right.

Comment: I just pasted the code from getValue into getTally (and changed the data.values to enemyTally.cities), and tried it again to no avail. The problem persists. Also, I just pasted my code into the original; my clean up was bad. If you could double check the corrected version, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Never mind, I'm an idiot. I had enemyTally.getTally=new function(level){...} in my real code. The new screwed everything up. It works now. Sorry, folk.